# Injecting memorycache into a .NET 5 console app

Tags: c#, console-application, backgroundworker, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 console app that will run a long running process in a background worker.  I am getting a compilation error advising that:

'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMemoryCache' and no accessible extension method 'AddMemoryCache' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MyBot;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddSingleton<User>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

I want to inject a memory cache into my Worker class, and intended to register it here in my startup code.  Note - not registering the MemoryCache causes as dependency resolution problem at runtime.

A lot of examples advice the AddMemoryCache can be used, however, my application in not an ASP.NET application where most of the examples are show.

My worker class looks like this:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private User _user;
        private IMemoryCache _cache;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, User user, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _user = user;
            _cache = memoryCache;
        }
```

How can I inject a MemoryCache object into my Worker class in a non asp.net application ?  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, missing a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll assembly in your project?

Comment: @sbecker - Thanks ever so much you are correct.  Added it as a nuget and now works.  Thanks -

Comment: I added an Answer. Not very thorough. But maybe you can mark it as correct if nobody else posts something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the memory cache, you have to make sure the project has a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll assembly.
As can be seen in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.memorycacheservicecollectionextensions.addmemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) of the extension method AddMemoryCache().

Comment: After moving to .net5.0, this is the ideal solution. For me, I was using EfCore and i removed them as i was not using it anymore since we adopted Micro services and we use Dapper, so after i removed the EFCore from my related apps, and also ported to .net5.0, i started seeing this error until i added this from nuget.